# Vertical line in front of text in a UILabel. Like blockquotes

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm building a small app and wan't to display quotes in a UITableView. I'm using custom UITableViewCells with a bunch of UILabels, one for the headline and one for quote and more labels for more information.

I want to display the quote with a vertical line on the left side in front of the text. Like some blockquotes. Here is an example from Reeder-App, it does it exactly the way I want it.

[image: Example image]

Is there a simple way to do this, maybe with attributed strings? A hint would be awesome, because I haven't got an idea to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the textheight like:

```
CGSize textHeight = [textLabel.text sizeWithFont:textLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textLabel.frame.size.width, 99999999)];
```

Then draw the line like:

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 5, textHeight.height)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:lineView];
```